# javascript: strict mode and objects

Tags: javascript, object

I had some code that constructed an object:

```
function gridObjConst(id, itemName, itemPrice, itemListPrice, width, height, imgName) {

    this.id = id;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    this.itemListPrice = itemListPrice;
    this.width = width; 
    this.height = height; 
    this.imgName = imgName;

    return this;
}
```

I used the w3schools page as a guide: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

It all worked fine. Then I added "use strict" to the top of my code and this function broke. Firebug reported: this is undefined - this.id = id

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you use `new gridObjConst(...)` or just `gridObjConst(...)`?

Comment: Also: you might want to look for [a more reliable source than w3schools](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you are calling your constructor function without the `new` operator. You need to do this:

```
var myGridObjConst = new gridObjConst();
```

When you call the function without the `new` operator, `this` refers to the Window, but in strict mode it [does not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript), hence your error.

Also note that you don't need to `return this;` from a constructor function. `this` will be returned automatically.

---

As noted by @JoachimSauer, you should look at using MDN instead of W3Schools when learning JavaScript. The fact that prototypes are not mentioned anywhere on that page you linked to is absolutely ridiculous.